# What is the strength of Coulomb crystals?

Tags: crystals, elasticity, neutron-stars, ions, white-dwarfs

[Coulomb crystals](https://phys.au.dk/fileadmin/site_files/forskning/iontrap/pdfs/IonCoulombCrystals_Drewsen_2015.pdf) are solid crystals made of ions embedded in an electron gas. They constitute much of white dwarfs and the crust of neutron stars. In the case of neutron stars it is [known that they are very resilient](https://academic.oup.com/mnrasl/article/407/1/L54/1052204?login=true).

The shear modulus at $T=0$ is given by $\sim (Ze)^2n^{4/3} \sim 10^{29}$ Pa for neutron star crust (found in [(Smoluchowski 1970)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.24.923), but I couldn't find the source in the references he used). Simulations in ([Hoffman & Heyl 2012](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/426/3/2404/989134?login=true)) support it and give the breaking strain as 0.1. The superlinear scaling with ion number density gives enormous strength.

But what are the tensile and compressive strengths? What about the elastic and bulk modulus? I have not seen them in the Coulomb crystal literature, but surely they must be somewhere?

Comment: I was intrigued  and searched. found this https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/496/1/012010/pdf "Let us outline the calculation of the Coulomb crystal elastic moduli."  talks also about compressibility.

Comment: The plot of Dragon's Egg by Robert Forward turns on these properties.

Comment: @annav - Great find! Thanks, now I have some more reading.